# highlight specific text in the content box

Tags: content

This is an idea that came through my mind, and I would like to know if possible and how to approach it if so...

I have my own wordpress framework that I use as based for all my projects, I manage the content position generated in the content box using shortcodes which respond to an especific div with a location...

Said this, sometimes I find myself into a mess really hard to understand, for sample:

[one_column]
content
[/one_column]
[one_column]
content
[/one_column]
[one_column]
content
[/one_column]
[one_column]
content
[/one_column]

when the among of text is big, is hard to find where the shortcodes are placed.

So, is there any way to highlight the shortcode (like with a different color) into the content box? or maybe easier, is there any way to indent the content and keep that indent once I save or update the post?

I would like to hear you opinion,

Thanks in advanced.

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of doing this is with JavaScript to regex your parameter and apply a css style to them on the fly.

Check out these jquery plugin for ideas:
https://github.com/jbr/jQuery.highlightRegex
http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html

Comment: thanks a ton, looks like what I'm looking for! I'd appreciate you help

Comment: hi @andrewkthx - did you ever get this working? if you did i'd love to find out how! i've tried jQuery highlight with a regex (`/\[.*\]/ig`), it works in other places but not in the editor.